# what is the difference between "ng generate universal" and "ng add @nguniversal/express-engine"?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am little bit confused by angular official doc. I was trying to learn how to use Angular universal to build something. But I saw this command in the doc:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

which is quoted from https://angular.io/guide/universal.

But AFAIK there is another command called "ng generate universal".

To my guess.., ng generate universal is part of ng add @nguniversal/express-engine(am I right?), So what is the main difference  between those two commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng add` is a schematic that first *installs* the `@nguniversal/express-engine` here. That will provide your local `ng` CLI with some extra commands - one of which is ng generate universal. It will do so by installing the npm package (and potentially adjusting some of your local files).

`ng universal` is another schematic, which will (with the help of the newly installed package from the previous step) create the universal app.

Think about what happens when you, e.g. `ng add @angular/material`.

That installs the @angular/material package (and updates your project files by modifying package.json and maybe other stuff).

With those  installed, you can now generate material components, e.g. table or a dashboard.

It's the same here. They're different schematics - at a very abstract level, they do the same thing - modify files in your project directory), but specifically "add" has a different job then "generate".

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much :D